# MobileFirst SplashScreen issue with Direct Update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are facing this issue where our splash screen icon, shifts to the right once we receive direct update. But in normal app behaviour it works with no issues.

[image]

[image]

Are we missing something?

Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

Comment: What is "normal app behaviour"? is this an ipad app? iphone app? meant to be rotated...?

Comment: normal behaviour means the app launches and the icon in the middle. this is iPad, yes it can be rotated.

Comment: This icon is part of the app or part of the splash screen?

Comment: splashscreen, it is not separate.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a bug. I suggest that you will open an IBM PMR in order to have the dev team investigate an possibly provide an iFix. There should be no reason for the background to shift position during Direct Update.

When you open the mention, mention the iOS version and device type.